# Robocopy file to random named folder

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm creating a script to automatically copy and paste bookmarks to x amount of computers.

Robocopy the Mozilla Bookmarks which are stored in a file called `places.sqlite` on a drive. To the destination

```
Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\*RANDOM PROFILE NAME\places.sqlite
```

I can't find a solution to copy this file to the destination due to every windows profile and computer gets a random profile name created. I tried with a star * as you can see in the code because I thought a star choices the newest folder (last changed).

The code is:

```
$env:homeshare
$env:username

Robocopy "$env:homeshare\ComputerChange\" "C:\Users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\" "places.sqlite" /COPY:DAT
```

How do I edit the code so it chooses the random named folder? Is it possible to copy the places.sqlite to ALL folder in the Profiles\ folder?

Appreciate the help

Comment: One profile folder should have the extension `.default` Also there is a file `Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profile.ini` with one section containing `Standard=1` and the path.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I exactly point the directory to the folder with the.default extension? *.default command doesn't work. "...AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\" "places.sqlite" /COPY:DAT

Comment: You could change to that folder by `pushd "$($env:userprofile)\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"` and copy there.

Comment: You could use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` on `Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` to first find the folders before copying.